# When running an ANCOVA with two time points, how do you include a covariate that only has data at baseline?

Tags: r, anova, ancova

I am running an ANCOVA where insufficiently active adults were recruited in self-selected teams (N = 24) to receive a web-based intervention with gamification component (TECH+C) or without (TECH). At baseline and 12-week follow-up, PA and SB were measured using 7 days of accelerometry (Actigraph GT9X Link). The main effect of group (TECH vs. TECH+C) and time (baseline vs. follow-up) were examined with a 2x2 ANCOVA, controlling for age, gender, wear time, team and daily steps at baseline.

A big issue that I am running across is that daily steps is only at baseline.

When I run the R script:

```
aov2 <-aov(SB_avg ~ Age+ Gender+ Group + TimePoint + Group:TimePoint, data = All)
aov3 <-aov(SB_avg ~ Age+ Gender+ Group + TimePoint + Group:TimePoint, data = All)
aov4 <-aov(SB_avg ~ Age+ Gender+ WearTime_avg+ Group + TimePoint + Group:TimePoint, data = All)
aov5 <-aov(SB_avg ~ Age+ Gender+ WearTime_avg+ TeamID+ Group + TimePoint + Group:TimePoint, data = All)
aov6 <-aov(SB_avg ~ Age+ Gender+ WearTime_avg+ TeamID+ DailySteps + Group+ TimePoint + Group:TimePoint, data = All,na.action = na.exclude)
aov7 <-aov(SB_avg ~ Age+ Gender+ WearTime_avg+ TeamID+ DailySteps + Group, data = All,na.action = na.exclude)
```

I am met with an error

```
“Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
 contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels”
```

Is there a way to control for baseline daily steps in this ANCOVA without having the time two data points? I know daily steps to be highly correlated to SB and don't want to not account for that error variance.